# cronjob is not running in Docker container throw Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I have an issue when I run docker container the cronjob services are running but the cronjob is not executed as per schedule, I want to achieve is without attaching a volume

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:8.9.1         
RUN apt update && apt-get install -y cron vim
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /srv/image-server/current/
COPY . .
RUN  npm i 
RUN  cd /tmp && touch abc && mkdir test
ENTRYPOINT  sh start.sh
```

and also share the `start.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
/etc/init.d/cron start
echo "* * * * * rm -rf /tmp/*" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
echo "#" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
/etc/init.d/cron status
node server.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the log file is not getting created, try to make an empty log file first and re run it

try this dockerfile i have tested it with and crons are running succesfully.

```
FROM node:8.9.1         
RUN apt update 
RUN apt-get install cron vim -y
RUN mkdir app && touch /var/log/mylog.log
WORKDIR /srv/image-server/current/
COPY ./cronjob /etc/cron.d/container_cronjob
COPY . /srv/image-server/current/
RUN  npm i 
RUN chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/container_cronjob
RUN chmod 777 start.sh
CMD cron && node server.js
```

i have stored the crons in crontab

```
* 0 * * * root /srv/image-server/current/start.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

here is start.sh file content

```
rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the image `node:8.9.1` does not have `crontab` installed.

Change your `Dockerfile` to below:

```
FROM node:8.9.1         
RUN apt update && apt-get install -y cron vim
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /srv/image-server/current/
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x start.sh
RUN  npm i 
RUN  cd /tmp && touch abc && mkdir test
ENTRYPOINT  sh start.sh
```

Now your file and cronjobs should work when you rebuild the image and run it again.

Comment: when the container is run that time cron services are running but cronjob is not executed

Comment: I think that was due to permissions of files, I edited my answer, check it again

Comment: I'm not a JS dev, but do this and see the logs. Run `docker ps -a` and then get the name of exited container. Now run `docker logs NAME` and see the error or edit your question and inform me here

Answer (score 1):

There is a peculiar line at the top of a *working* user crontab:

```sh
head -n1 /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
```

Therefore it's best to follow the advice if you lack the desire to fight unexpected problems. Especially since there are several ways you can get the job done:

1. Write the job in `/etc/cron.d/somefile`:

```sh
# The syntax for this file is slightly different
# It requires you to write which user should run the job
#     m h dom mon dow user  command
echo "* * *   *   *   root  rm -rf /tmp/*" > /etc/cron.d/somejob
```

2. Write the jobs into a text file, then import with `crontab`:

```sh
echo "* * * * * rm -rf /tmp/*" > /tmp/crontab.txt
crontab /tmp/crontab.txt
# or, to import for specific user:
# crontab -u $USERNAME /tmp/crontab.txt
rm /tmp/crontab.txt
```

Also, I'd like to add that hardcoding cronjobs into a Dockerfile is rather annoying when it comes to changes. You'd have to rebuild the image to implement changes and push the new image to nodes. God save you from making a mistake here or you'd have to repeat that from the beginning. Because of that I started to write cron jobs into environment variables (`docker-compose` syntax):

```yaml
services:
  example:
    environment:
      CRON_USER: john  # <- they will have the crontab, root if undeclared
      CRONTAB: |
        # Now you can work with it like with a normal crontab

        PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
        FOO=bar
        * * * * * echo "I'm doing something useful" > /proc/1/fd/1
```

And this little piece of code does the conversion from an environment variable to a crontab:

```sh
if [ -n "$CRONTAB" ]; then # e.g. if non-zero length
    echo "$CRONTAB" > /tmp/crontab.txt

    if [ -n "$CRON_USER" ]; then
        echo "Setting up crontab for user '$CRON_USER'..."
        crontab -u "$CRON_USER" /tmp/crontab.txt
    else
        echo "Setting up crontab for root..."
        crontab /tmp/crontab.txt
    fi

    rm /tmp/crontab.txt
fi
```